# How can I renew a Users Facebook Access Token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-access-token

If a user loggs into my app with his facebook account I get an access token which is valid for 2 months. But what happens if the two months exceed and the user loggs into my app again? 
Do I get a new 2 month access token automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user will have to go through the normal authentication process that they did when they first installed the application.

During this process, Facebook will detect that the application has already been installed and refresh the access token.

So, to directly answer your question: **yes**, you will receive a new access token.