# Can I renew facebook token automatically?

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, token, koala, koala-gem

I am working on collaborative web platform by ruby on rails and it's connected with facebook app (v2) by Koala gem..

When a user register by facebook account, there is facebook token (expire after 60 days)

**The questions:**

1- when and how renew the token in normal cases?

2- Can I renew token for 60 days again before end validity of the token?

3- Can I renew token automatically when user used his account in app with old session (without new sign in), or the user must sign out and sign in again to renew token?

I show [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18107343/1123386), but the tokens of users doesn't renew automatically when users visit to site with old sessions (without signin), do I have to finish their sessions  automatically to force them to sign in  again?

Answer (score 2):

1 - When the user visits your App again

2 - Afaik you can only refresh them after the old one is not valid anymore. Not entirely sure about that though, as i have never tried.

3 - You can only renew the token with user interaction. if it would be possible to auto-renew, there would be no need for short- and long-living tokens at all.

Btw, renewal is very easy with the JavaScript SDK, by just calling `FB.getLoginStatus` on page load. In general, try to avoid using Tokens while the user is offline.